# java regex- get specific index where not have a specific word before

Tags: java, regex, xml, regex-negation

Im trying to add the double quote on a xml string only on specific place.

Here an example of xml content

```
    <opr:sec name=display>
     <opr:fld name=fieldName>Value1</opr:fld>
     <opr:fld name=someName>value2</opr:fld>
```

I need to add double quote like : name=**"**fieldName**"** and the field names are different each line.

The first double quote are simple using the **name=** that need to be before

But for the closing double quote i think to use the **>** sign, but need to avoid the **fld** at end.

How i regex a letter that **don't** have a specific text before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler way to do what you want.
Use this regex :
`name=([^>]*)>`
And replace it by :
`name="$1">`

Comment: @Benius: Anytime ! Just something about my answer, though : It won't work if there is a `>` inside the field you want to quote. If this is your case, I can update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can  use capturing blocks, split your line into 3 blocks and reconstruct it from the pieces:

```
String line = "<opr:fld name=fieldName>Value1</opr:fld>";
String regex = "(.*name=)(.*)(>.*>)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
matcher.matches();
String result = matcher.group(1) + "\"" + matcher.group(2) + "\"" + matcher.group(3);
System.out.println(result);
```